# SQL Server - Order by name from Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below, my second case does not work because I'm referencing the name from the subquery. What is a good solution to this problem? Also, I'm declaring the SortBy parameter... just didn't include that in the example. Thank you so much for any help!

```
SELECT
 a.[PostID]
,a.[Title]
,a.[Date_Created] 
,(SELECT COUNT(VoteID) AS VoteCount 
     FROM [VoteTable] WHERE [PostID] = a.[PostID]) AS VoteCount

FROM [PostTable] a
INNER JOIN [Users] b
ON a.Created_UserID = b.UserID
WHERE a.Approved = 1

ORDER BY 
CASE @SortBy
    WHEN 1 THEN a.[Date_Created] END DESC,
CASE @SortBy
    WHEN 2 THEN [VoteCount] END DESC
```

Comment: It's telling me invalid column name. SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
WHEN 2 THEN [VoteCount] END DESC
```

With:

```
WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT COUNT(VoteID) AS VoteCount 
 FROM [VoteTable] WHERE [PostID] = a.[PostID]) END DESC
```

Comment: This is actually working... Should Kcoder's example be modified at all? Not getting any errors. About to click that beautiful check mark!

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson Yes it appears to be working. I'm still testing.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson I stand corrected then.  I guess there's something about this particular syntax that causes the column alias to break.

Comment: Should I use a different solution? It appears to be working fine. I'll accept the answer for my unique situation, but if there's a better way I'm all ears. Thank you all so much!

Comment: I"m surprised SQL Server accepted the alias (i.e. "AS VoteCount") in the `ORDER BY`.   It never has for me...

Answer (score 2):

Repeating the expression is one way, as is placing it in a subquery or CTE, e.g.:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT
   a.PostID
  ,a.Title
  ,a.Date_Created 
  ,(SELECT COUNT(VoteID)  
     FROM VoteTable WHERE PostID = a.PostID) AS VoteCount
   FROM dbo.PostTable AS a
   INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS b
   ON a.Created_UserID = b.UserID
   WHERE a.Approved = 1
)
SELECT PostID, Title, Date_Created, VoteCount
FROM cte
ORDER BY 
  CASE @SortBy
    WHEN 1 THEN Date_Created END DESC,
  CASE @SortBy
    WHEN 2 THEN VoteCount END DESC;
```

But instead of repeating the expression, it doesn't seem to matter if you really perform a conditional for the second order by. So why not simply change your existing `ORDER BY` to:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @SortBy = 1 THEN a.Date_Created END DESC,
         VoteCount DESC;
```

In this case if `@SortBy` is 2, the first expression is `NULL`, and so your desired ordering is still achieved. When `@SortBy` is 1, it's ordered by date descending, and unless there are a lot of ties with `Date_Created` and in that case you *don't* want to see those ties sorted by `VoteCount DESC`, the secondary order by is inconsequential, so you don't need to wrap it in a second `CASE` expression.

The reason, by the way, is that when you introduce a `CASE` expression to the `ORDER BY`, you change the way SQL Server might parse/evaluate the query, and you can no longer reference an alias from the `SELECT` list. This is why removing the `CASE` from the `ORDER BY` clause no longer complains about an invalid column name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 a.[PostID]
,a.[Title]
,a.[Date_Created] 
,V.VoteCount 
FROM [PostTable] a
INNER JOIN (SELECT PostID, COUNT(VoteID) AS VoteCount GROUP BY PostID) V
     ON V.[PostID] = a.[PostID]
INNER JOIN [Users] b
ON a.Created_UserID = b.UserID
WHERE a.Approved = 1
ORDER BY 
CASE @SortBy
    WHEN 1 THEN a.[Date_Created] END DESC,
CASE @SortBy
    WHEN 2 THEN V.[VoteCount] END DESC
```