# SQL dynamic ORDER BY using alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server, I can order a normal `SELECT` query using an alias:

```
SELECT   
   u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName as PhysicianName, COUNT(r.Id) as ReferralsCount
FROM     
   Referrals r 
INNER JOIN
   Users u ON r.PhysicianId = u.Id
GROUP BY 
   r.PhysicianId, u.FirstName, u.LastName
ORDER BY 
   PhysicianName
```

However, attempting to do the same thing with a dynamic `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT   
   u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName as PhysicianName, COUNT(r.Id) as ReferralsCount
FROM     
   Referrals r 
INNER JOIN
   Users u ON r.PhysicianId = u.Id
GROUP 
   BY r.PhysicianId, u.FirstName, u.LastName
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @orderby = 'PhysicianName' THEN PhysicianName END,
    CASE WHEN @orderby = 'ReferralsCount' THEN ReferralsCount END
```

Produces the following error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Invalid column name 'PhysicianName'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Invalid column name 'ReferralsCount'.

Comment: how is the original query generated?

Comment: I typed it into MSSQL Management Studio.

Comment: Potential duplicate except it has a terrible accepted answer IMHO : http://stackoverflow.com/q/18091886/61305

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Column aliases defined in the `SELECT` can only be used in the `ORDER BY` on their own. Not in an expression.

You can adjust your original attempt as follows.

```
;WITH T
     AS (SELECT u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName AS PhysicianName,
                COUNT(r.Id)                    AS ReferralsCount
         FROM   Referrals r
                INNER JOIN Users u
                  ON r.PhysicianId = u.Id
         GROUP  BY r.PhysicianId,
                   u.FirstName,
                   u.LastName)
SELECT *
FROM   T
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN @orderby = 'PhysicianName' THEN PhysicianName
          END,
          CASE
            WHEN @orderby = 'ReferralsCount' THEN ReferralsCount
          END
```

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but is it possible to specify an `ELSE` when declaring the CASE statements like this, so I can provide a fallback sort order?

Comment: You could add another `CASE WHEN @orderby NOT IN ('PhysicianName','ReferralsCount') THEN someting_else END`

Comment: Or just add `, something_else` since - if it's not `PhysicianName` or `ReferralsCount` then that fallback sort order will be used (and in most cases it won't affect the chosen primary ordering in a noticeable way).